# How do I modify a region's color in a fold?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, plugin-vimwiki

I'm using the vimwiki plugin. I can successfully change the header colors with something like this:

```
hi VimwikiHeader1 ctermfg=black
hi VimwikiHeader2 ctermfg=darkblue
hi VimwikiHeader3 ctermfg=cyan
hi VimwikiHeader4 ctermfg=yellow
hi VimwikiHeader5 ctermfg=blue
hi VimwikiHeader6 ctermfg=red
```

However, when folded, the header colors get overridden by the `Folded` region.

So, I tried this:

```
hi Folded ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE
```

While this removes the colors, the ctermfg color of the folds is the default color, grey. So the Folded region still appears to override the `VimwikiHeader` region highlight.

I also tried creating a new region that was contained with `Folded` and `VimWikiHeaderX` but I couldn't get that working.

Comment: While that does change the color for `VimwikiHeaderX`, but I'd like to have a different color for each of the 6 header levels when folded.

Comment: The vimwiki groups are probably syntax groups, whereas the folded group is more of  a UI group. I suspect the latter simply overrides the former in cases like this

Comment: Yeah, I hunted around quite a bit and came up empty. I don't think what I want to do is possible.

Comment: Yeah I looked at this before and as far as I can tell Vim currently doesn't support setting custom colors inside folded groups... You might consider filing a feature request [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues) or discussing it on one of Vim's [mailing lists](https://www.vim.org/community.php).